# Textarea set HTML Value

Tags: cordova, textarea, sencha-touch

I'm creating an mobile app (PhoneGap) where there are news that the user can edit. The content of the news is in HTML and when the user wants to edit the news it switches to a Form Panel and sets the value of a text area to the content value of the news. The problem is I get HTML tags in the text area. So my question is, is there a way to remove/hide these tags from the content of the news ?

I have tried slash nick's technique but when I do :

```
console.log(record.data.content.textContent);
```

I get

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSRangeException> *** -[JKArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally went for that method even though it removes all HTML tags as well

[Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) on the element to get it's text.  This will work in Firefox, Chrome and IE9.  For older versions IE you can use `innerText`.

```
var text, 
    editElement = document.getElementsById("elementToEdit");​

if (editElement​.textContent) {
   text = editElement​.textContent;
} else {
   text = editElement.innerText;
}

document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = text;​
```

However, this will remove any tags within the content and just leave the text.

Comment: But I don't need to get text from an element, I already have to text in a variable. And you method doesn't apply for my case. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an editor like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) or [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com) to your application.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a mobile app developed with PhoneGap so editors are too complicated for small screens. Thanks anyway